# Python/Wand/Imagemagick: Adding caption

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I am trying to replicate some annotation examples. Below is my code and I am wondering what's going wrong.

```
from wand.font import Font
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
        
file1 = 'Lenna.jpg' #Download from here https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png
myImage = Image(filename=file1)
myImage.font = Font('C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\FONTS\\cyrvetic.ttf')
myImage.GRAVITY_TYPES=("southeast")
myImage.caption = ("Some text here",50,50,200,200)
display(myImage)
```

Eventually I want to replicate this command:

```
convert Lenna.jpg -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -pointsize 24 -gravity SouthEast -annotate +50+10 "Some text here" Lenna2.jpg
```

Any idea what's going wrong in the above code?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that there is something going wrong?

Comment: Why do you not use annotate in Python Wand rather than caption?

Comment: Thanks. It has been very hard to find documentation (for python/wand) to do it right . I tried annotate and I get it but can't find options to change the font color. I was expecting it to be either as font_color or text_color, but neither exist. I get dark letters on dark background.

Comment: try setting the fill_color and or stroke_color properties before annotate

Comment: Thanks. I found some other post. It works on Windows, but on Linux I get AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'annotate'.

Comment: That is odd. The Wand maintainer, Eric McConville, will need to comment about this.

Comment: Can you please describe in the question what the problem was, so that others having the same problem can find it in the future?

Comment: The missing `annotate` method is not related to Windows or Linux, but different versions of Wand. It's likely your Linux box is running a version before Wand-0.5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that worked (but only on Windows, not on Linux)

```
    from wand.drawing import Drawing
    from wand.color import Color
    with Drawing() as ctx:
        ctx.font_family = 'Times New Roman, Nimbus Roman No9'
        ctx.font_size = 28
        ctx.fill_color = Color('blue')
        ctx.stroke_color = Color('blue')
        ctx.gravity = "south_east"
        myImage.annotate("Some text", ctx, 20, 30) #Windows
```

For Linux, the last line needs to be changed.

```
    from wand.drawing import Drawing
    from wand.color import Color
    with Drawing() as ctx:
        ctx.font_family = 'Times New Roman, Nimbus Roman No9'
        ctx.font_size = 28
        ctx.fill_color = Color('blue')
        ctx.stroke_color = Color('blue')
        ctx.gravity = "south_east"
        #myImage.annotate("Some text", ctx, 20, 30) #Windows
        ctx.text(20, 30, "Some text") #Linux
        ctx.draw(myImage) #Linux
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine calling myImage.annotate(...) works